# Router-outlet not appearing below navbar module

Tags: html, css, angular, tailwind-css, angular-routing

I am trying to create a website using angular. I am done with the navbar, but when I try to add the next module, it is not appearing under the navbar module.

The app.component.html looks like this:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And my homepage.component.html looks like this:

```
<h2>homepage component works!!</h2>
```

app-routing.component.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomepageComponent } from './pages/homepage/homepage.component';

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'home',
  component: HomepageComponent
},
{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: 'home',
  pathMatch: 'full'
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

When I change my navbar template to this:

```
    <h2>Navbar works!!</h2>
```

the homepage component is appearing below the navbar, as it should. But when I add my styling to the navbar, it no longer appears under the navbar, appearing in the wrong position. This is the designed navbar template:

```
    <div class="absolute inset-x-0 top-0 z-50 bg-gradient-to-b from-orange-400 to-[#e1d471]">
    <nav class="flex items-center justify-between p-6 lg:px-8 " aria-label="Global">
        <!-- Logo -->
```

I am using TailwindCSS for styling. What could be the problem, and how can I fix this?
[image: Output page]

I am trying to create a homepage for a product, but the homepage is not appearing under the navbar. Instead, it is appearing behind the navbar.

Comment: Have you declared the `HomepageComponent` in the `declarations:[]` array in the `app.module.ts`?

Comment: @Prav Yes, I have declared the HomepageComponent

Comment: Does it show the `HomepageComponent` HTML in the Inspect tool? Can you also try updating the RouterModule? `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false })`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation, the content of `<router-outlet>` *does* show up on the page; albeit in the wrong place. So, it is *not* Angular issue; let alone Angular routing. And looking on your screen shot, you have some CSS applied.

The next step would be to turn off all CSS and confirm that you get your home component HTML under the navbar content. If you get that, then start analyzing CSS of the home component. In case you have CSS *inside* Home component - remove it. If you have questions, probably worth tagging it with CSS.